# Using Gnu Parallel to run a folder of tests against my program

Tags: parallel-processing, gnu-parallel

I am trying to use gnu parallel to run tests. I have tried this command but it doesnt work and I dont know what im doing wrong.

```
seq 01 35 | parallel java -javaagent:build/libs/pddl4j-3.0.21-SNAPSHOT.jar 
-server -Xms2048m -Xmx2048m fr.uga.pddl4j.planners.hsp.HSP -o pddl/blocksworld/
domain.pddl -f pddl/blocksworld/p{}.pddl -i 8 >> pddl{}.txt
```

This is what I have tried to run which will run my program against all of the test files inside the folder "blocksworld"

```
java -javaagent:build/libs/pddl4j-3.0.21-SNAPSHOT.jar -server -Xms2048m -Xmx2048m 
fr.uga.pddl4j.planners.hsp.HSP -o pddl/blocksworld/
domain.pddl -f pddl/blocksworld/p01.pddl -i 8 >> pddl01.txt
```

This above is what I use to run just one test and save the output to a txt file. Can anyone help so I can use parallel to run them in parallel please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to quote the '>>'.

```
seq 01 35 | parallel java -javaagent:build/libs/pddl4j-3.0.21-SNAPSHOT.jar 
-server -Xms2048m -Xmx2048m fr.uga.pddl4j.planners.hsp.HSP -o pddl/blocksworld/
domain.pddl -f pddl/blocksworld/p{}.pddl -i 8 '>>' pddl{}.txt
```